If a trigger runs an update will it ALWAYS have the same timestamp for a temporal table?
Background
Here is an example near to what I am working with:
CREATE TABLE sandboxTesting.TemporalTest (    
    GroupNumber VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    StartEffectiveWhen DATE NOT NULL,
    EndEffectiveWhen DATE NULL,
    ModifiedWhen DATETIME NULL,
    IsReady BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    RowValidFrom DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    RowValidTo DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (RowValidFrom, RowValidTo),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TemporalTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
    (
        GroupNumber, StartEffectiveWhen
    )
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING=ON (HISTORY_TABLE=sandboxTesting.TemporalTestHistory))
GO 

CREATE TRIGGER sandboxTesting.OnModify ON sandboxTesting.TemporalTest AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    
    UPDATE  temporalTst
    SET     temporalTst.IsReady = 0,
            temporalTst.ModifiedWhen = GETDATE()
    FROM    sandboxTesting.TemporalTest temporalTst
            JOIN deleted del
                ON del.GroupNumber = temporalTst.GroupNumber
                AND del.StartEffectiveWhen = temporalTst.StartEffectiveWhen
    WHERE   -- All business columns go here with OR statements in between them.
            -- The idea is that if anything changes except the IsReady flag, then we 
            -- set the IsReady back to false.  (IsReady has to be set by itself)
            del.EndEffectiveWhen <> temporalTst.EndEffectiveWhen 
            OR (del.EndEffectiveWhen IS NULL AND temporalTst.EndEffectiveWhen IS NOT NULL)
            OR (del.EndEffectiveWhen IS NOT NULL AND temporalTst.EndEffectiveWhen IS NULL)
END
GO

-- Insert new test
INSERT INTO [sandboxTesting].[TemporalTest] ([GroupNumber], [StartEffectiveWhen], [EndEffectiveWhen],  [ModifiedWhen])
VALUES ('12345', '2024-01-1', NULL, NULL)
GO

-- Set is as ready 
UPDATE  sandboxTesting.TemporalTest
SET     IsReady = 1
WHERE   GroupNumber = '12345' AND StartEffectiveWhen = '2024-01-1'
GO 

-- Change the End date
UPDATE  sandboxTesting.TemporalTest
SET     EndEffectiveWhen = '2024-09-02'
WHERE   GroupNumber = '12345' AND StartEffectiveWhen = '2024-01-1'
        
-- Set the new end date as ready for billing.
UPDATE  sandboxTesting.TemporalTest
SET     IsReady = 1
WHERE   GroupNumber = '12345' AND StartEffectiveWhen = '2024-01-1'
GO 


-- Select the Data
SELECT * FROM sandboxTesting.TemporalTest for SYSTEM_TIME ALL 
ORDER BY GroupNumber, StartEffectiveWhen desc, RowValidFrom DESC, RowValidTo DESC, ModifiedWhen desc

-- Select the Raw Data (for comparison)
SELECT * FROM sandboxTesting.TemporalTest
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM sandboxTesting.TemporalTestHistory
ORDER BY GroupNumber, StartEffectiveWhen desc, RowValidFrom DESC, RowValidTo DESC, ModifiedWhen desc

When I run this, this is the first result:



GroupNumber
StartEffectiveWhen
EndEffectiveWhen
ModifiedWhen
IsReady
RowValidFrom
RowValidTo




12345
2024-01-01
2024-09-02
2024-08-29 17:15:28.587
1
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223
9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999


12345
2024-01-01
NULL
NULL
1
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5295658
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223


12345
2024-01-01
NULL
NULL
0
2024-08-29 23:15:28.4826980
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5295658



And the second set of output looks like this:



GroupNumber
StartEffectiveWhen
EndEffectiveWhen
ModifiedWhen
IsReady
RowValidFrom
RowValidTo




12345
2024-01-01
2024-09-02
2024-08-29 17:15:28.587
1
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223
9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999


12345
2024-01-01
2024-09-02
2024-08-29 17:15:28.587
0
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223


12345
2024-01-01
2024-09-02
NULL
1
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223


12345
2024-01-01
NULL
NULL
1
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5295658
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5764223


12345
2024-01-01
NULL
NULL
0
2024-08-29 23:15:28.4826980
2024-08-29 23:15:28.5295658



This is different because the first query result uses the for SYSTEM_TIME ALL clause, while the second one just queries the raw data.
The difference is that, in the first data set, the second and third rows of the second data set have been filtered out.  They have been removed because the second and third rows have a start date and end date that are the same.  (Basically saying those rows were never really in effect.)
Question
What I need to know is, can I depend on this "zero time difference" always being there for data that was updated via an AFTER trigger?  (I need to write some queries that will fail if this is not the case.)
What I mean by that is this:  If my server was being hammered by thousands of queries all doing crazy amounts of IO and calculations, would the RowValidFrom and RowValidTo values for the second and third rows of the second dataset still have a difference of 0?
Put another way, are these values the same because of transaction logic?  Or are they the same because my server is fast and not really under any pressure right now?


can I depend on this "zero time difference" always being there for data that was updated via an AFTER trigger

No. Rows with a zero-validity period appear whenever you update the same row multiple times within the same transaction (even if no column values are actually changed). Only the final (effective) row change within a transaction can have a non-zero validity period.
In your case, the trigger makes the final change so it's validity period will be non-zero, in general. It can still be zero length if the whole transaction and a subsequent change completes below the resolution of the timer in use.
Remember a trigger runs in the transaction of the triggering statement. Even if there's no explicit or implicit transaction, there's always the autocommit transaction started by the originating update.

When I run your example as a single batch with execution plans turned off to minimise delays between statements, I see:

The ASOF query returns only two rows because the statements complete so quickly three of the history entries have zero-validity periods.
In particular, changing the end date, the subsequent trigger execution, and finally setting IsReady to 1 all appear to complete instantaneously. As a result, the ASOF view makes it look as if IsReady was never set to zero.
You can avoid this sort of outcome in your testing by introducing a small WAITFOR delay in the trigger or turning actual execution plans on in SSMS. In any event, the extra delay will prevent very fast operations being recorded with zero validity periods.
With execution plans on, I see:

The delays mean the ASOF query now shows both IsReady transitions from 0 to 1.
You could also run your test statements one at a time instead of all at once in a single batch.

None of this will alter the fact that changes made by a trigger occur within the transaction of the triggering statement, will be the final change to a particular row inside that transaction, and therefore the only event with a non-zero validity period.

This is exactly what I was hoping for!  I need to be sure that the changes made by the trigger will ALWAYS be represented with the changes that caused the trigger.  In this case, that means that (when using FOR SYSTEM TIME ALL) that when the EndEffectiveWhen is changed, there is no chance that the row that still has the IsReady = 1 is retuned (unless a separate operation is run to set IsReady  to 1). I need to have any change to EndEffecitveWhen mark the row as not ready anymore, That way I can make a view that will only return the most recent "Ready/Published" row for a GroupNumber. Thanks!

In the scenario you build, NO, the 2nd row cannot be sure it was updated by AFTER trigger. But the 3th row can be treated as a action which fire the trigger.
I ran your script on my slow laptop, result as this

The 2nd row's from&to time are not same. But the 3th row has same from&to time, this is because one row in TemporalTest was modified mutiple times in same transation. In your sample, phase 1: update EndEffectiveWhen, this was recorded in 3th row; phase 2: AFTER TRIGGER was fired to update IsReady, this was recorded in 2nd row. History table marks those records with same ValidFrom and ValidTo time to identify the updates were performed on same PK within same transation, and record transation end time in last history row's ValidTo. Your can check the description in document.
